# If you wash blood off your hands (literally), can you eat with your hands immediately thereafter?

Tags: food, eating, blood

I heard before that if someone washes blood off a service, forensics experts can still determine if blood was there (I think using luminol?). This got me thinking: If the experts' ability to detect blood implies that water couldn't completely wash blood off the service, would that also imply that washing one's hands can't completely remove all blood on one's hands? And if it is forbidden to consume blood, would it be forbidden to eat any food you touch with your hands immediately after washing them?

Since you shouldn't consume blood, does washing your hands remove blood completely from your hands? If not, can your hands still contaminate food in such a scenario? If this would cause you hands to contaminate what it touches, would it be forbidden to eat with your hands immediately after washing blood off them?

Comment: Netilat Yadayim is not a wash for hygienical reasons. It is a ritual washing of the hands. Maybe a decent medical scrub is necessary to completely remove all traces of blood, but is that really the point when doing Netilat Yadayim?

Comment: Is your concern a barrier to a valid hand washing for bread? Is your question about accidentally eating blood? Is your question about לא תאכלו על הדם? Please [edit] to clarify

Comment: @Shmuel My question wasn't clear, so I edited it just now. My concern is that if traces of blood are still on your hand, what if that would make forbidden any food you touch? Does a regular washing of the hands (I shouldn't have used the Netilat Yadayim tag) remove all blood? If not, is a regular handwashing insufficient to clean one's hands, making any food the person touches forbidden?

Comment: @DoubleAA I apologize for the confusion. My question is about accidentally eating blood, so I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Ritual washing cannot remove everything, as I already explained. But.... if, after washing, you find a trace of blood on your hand, and you can clearly see it. It would seem to me that you thoroughly scrub it and then do the ritual washing again. That's my logical answer, however, please consult your local Rabbi, as this logical answer is not backed up by any sources at this moment.

Comment: @Shmuel Okay, so if you wash your hands and no blood is visible, you don't have to worry about if, hypothetically, an invisible trace of blood could still be on your hand. Is this correct?

Comment: How would one know? Are we required to check our hands under Ultraviolet light to see if there still is some blood after already thoroughly washing the hands? It is even the case that the Nishmat Avraham (Orach Chayyim 4 19) writes that netilat yadayim is required only if blood was drawn for therapeutic purposes -eg. the patient needed his blood thinned. Taking blood for diagnostic purposes or donating blood to a blood bank does not require netilat yadayim. - https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/2859

Comment: Concerning food, if, for example, you have a cut, and some of the blood drips into the food. The Darkei Teshuvah 66:71 explains (see also Yad Avraham, Y.D. 66:10) that if the redness of the blood is still visible in the food, it is forbidden to eat (or drink) it. Similary, it would seem to me that if you have a little blood on your hand, if the redness is not visible anymore (due to some washing for example), it is okay. As I've mentioned before, are we meant to take Ultraviolet light and inspect our hands?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141705/discussion-between-shmuel-and-the-editor).

Comment: Judaism is not a microscopic religion. It is concerned with whether or not there is visible or tasteable blood, not forensic traces of blood remaining on the hands. The same applies to the kashrus of bugs, for instance, which is why we are not concerned about eating dust mites that are too small to perceive with the unaided eye. NB: If one could see something under optimal conditions (e.g., somebody with excellent vision examining in bright sunlight against a white background), that would be considered halachically visible (Tif'eres Yisra'el, Avoda Zara, Bo'az 2:3; Aruch HaShulchan, YD 83:15).

Comment: @Schmuel Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Fred Thank you for your explanation.